SQL Server Populate Local Table with Exec call
I have a very complex SQL Server procedure and the folks requesting the changes asked for additional data that comes from a secondary complex procedure. I am attempting to do the following:
In procedure 1, add the following code
DECLARE @daily_sales TABLE (...)

DECLARE @SQL_string varchar(8000) = 'EXEC PROCNAME @season_str = ''' + @season + ''', @perf_start_dt = ''' + cast(@begin_perf_dt as varchar) + ''' , @perf_end_dt = ''' + cast(@end_perf_dt as varchar)+ ''' ,  @sale_end_dt =  ''' + cast(@end_perf_dt as varchar) + ''', @mode =1'

SELECT @SQL_string

INSERT @daily_sales
    EXEC (@SQL_string)

SELECT * FROM @daily_sales

The select @sql_string returns the following:
EXEC PROC @season_str = '500', @perf_start_dt = 'Jan  3 2024 12:00AM' , @perf_end_dt = 'Nov 22 2024 12:00AM' ,  @sale_end_dt =  'Nov 22 2024 12:00AM', @mode =1

So the execute appears to look correctly.
However, no matter what I try, I keep getting the following error

Msg 8164, Level 16, State 1, Procedure PROC, Line 185 [Batch Start Line 9]
An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.

I get many many repeated lines of this.
I can't replicate the logic locally because its several thousand lines of very complex code, and all I really need is 5-6 of the columns of the output.
I tried using openrowset but it didn't work either as its all on the same server.
I can't figure out how to return the data and populate it into a local temp table (I tried both #table and @table, neither option worked).
I also researched the error message and couldn't find any other solutions for this issue.

Well the error is clear, you can't nest insert into ... exec so you have to find an alternative way to return data if you must do that. When I faced that issue I returned the dataset from one SP as XML.

You can use openquery and execute against own server though. if it didn't work, please add more info about one

@DaleK I researched that link shared in the other ticket and nothing advised there made it work. In short it didn't work

@siggemannen I tried openquery, openrowset, dynamic sql, it seems that my proc that i'm calling calls multiple other procs (which is why its complex and long and why i'm hoping to use it) but why i'm getting a nested error

well, did you remove the insert exec after converting your code to openquery?

You can't make nested insert into exec calls work. Hence you need an alternative way to return data which the duplicate link suggests
